# LeNet-5 - combining feature maps in C3 layer

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, convolutional-neural-network

Famous LeNet-5 architecture looks like this:
[image]

The output of layer S2 has dimension: 10x10x6 - so basically an image with 6 convultions applied to it to derive features.

If each dimension was again submitted to 6 filters the resulting output would be of 10x10x36 however it is 10x10x16. Initially I stumble on it but finnaly I udnerstood that this is done be combining inputs from layer S2 and applying one kernel on it as it's explained in the article:

> Layer C3 is a convolutional layer with 16 feature maps Each unit in
>   each feature map is connected to several 5x5 neighborhoods at
>   identical locations in a subset of S2s feature maps

.

> The rationale behind the connection scheme in table I is the
>   following The 1rst six C3 feature maps take inputs from every
>   contiguous subsets of three feature maps in S2. The next six take input
>   from every contiguous subset of four. The next three take input from
>   some discontinuous subsets of four Finally the last one takes input
>   from all S2 feature maps Layer C3 has 1,516 trainable parameters and
>   151,600 connections

and the roadmap of it is provided in the table:
[image]

What I am still not uderstand is how exactly should I combine them?

In previous layer I've just applied 6 kernels on 1 dimension, resulting in 6 dimensions what was understandable. Here I am a bit lost to be honest :(

Please help.
Mateusz

Comment: It is 16 kernels that take each take 6 channels. Any value the resulting 16 channels is a recombination of 5 * 5 * 16 values. It might be helpful to think of a filter over an RGB image (3 channels).

Comment: Thanks @SvanBalen. Thinking like the rgb channels really helped. But as I undertstod this way table above. Is it that kernel 0 would be 5*5*3 but kernel 6 would be 5*5*4? 
Or all of them are as you said 5*5*6 but some of the channels that are not makred as "X" above are zero matrix? 

If so, how from having 16 kernels all of them have depth of 6 I achieve feature map of 5*5*16? Do they apply some compbination on 6 channels to receive depth o 1?

Comment: I would think of it like this: each pixel in any of the 16 output layers is the result of a trainable operation applied over a spatial region of 5 by 5 on a 6 channel image. Yes some of these input channels are not considered for some of the output channels (I would think of that as rows of fixed zeroes in a tensor).

Comment: Ok. and then do I just sum the results of those 6 channels? [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-convolutional-neural-network-using-numpy-from-scratch-b30aac50e50a) I found this quote regarding convulving rgb picture: "If the image to be convolved has more than one channel, then the filter must has a depth equal to such number of channels. Convolution in this case is done by convolving each image channel with its corresponding channel in the filter. **Finally, the sum of the results** will be the output feature map.". Is it literally sum of corresponding cell in each of the channel?

Comment: I think you are now asking how a convolution works in depth, perhaps this explanation helps: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8240/how-do-convolutions-become-matrix-multiplications. All you need to envision now is that that process work in a 3d space.

Answer (score 0):

See this table, each row of which has 16 numbers. I don't know how to align them, so I posted a picture as well.

FILTER      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15
WEIGHTS     75  75  75  75  75  75  100     100     100     100     100     100     100     100     100     150
BIAS      1     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
TRAINABLE PARAMETERS    76  76  76  76  76  76  101     101     101     101     101     101     101     101     101     151

[image]

Comment: Please consider adding more text/explanation to your answer as pictures/links can sometimes become broken or unable to be viewed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The filter $0$ of C3 is generated from the filter $0,1,2$ of S2. The kernel size is $5x5$. The number of parameter is $5x5x3=75 + 1(bias) = 76$.
This applies to other filters as well. So overall, there are $76 + 76 +...+101+151 = 1516$ parameters.